# Google places, with different api keys getting "You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API."

Tags: google-places-api

With google places API, autocomplete. 
I'm getting the same response even when I create a new project, and put new API key in fetch.

Example:

```
mykey = different keys
```

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?types=(cities)&key=mykey&language=en&components=country:us

Any ideas why is google always responding with status `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT`?

Comment: Is it possible they've detected you're trying to bypass the quotas by using multiple keys and have throttled you at another (IP?) level?

Comment: Google Maps Platform now requires a billing account created for your project: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage-and-billing. Did you create billing account?

Comment: Didn't enable billing account. I will try that, thanks for comments